# Words meaning long-term success

Tags: single-word-requests, obscure-terms

I am looking for a word that means success, especially in the long-term.

i.e: Doing something today that will give you a **competitive advantage** in the future.

Bonus points for words that are not used very often.

Answer (score 1):

**Dominance** of a field is the highest form of long-term success.

Below is an example from a Stanford University computer science project called The Danger of Monopolies.

> It has also been claimed that Microsoft used its control over the operating system and graphical user interface markets to help its growth in the applications market. Microsoft executives spoke of a "Chinese wall" between the systems and applications groups, but they did admit that sometimes their own developers learned to take advantage of operating system features before other companies. (New York Times, 11/5/95) Furthermore, it was alleged that when Microsoft included a new technology called object linking and embedding (OLE) in Windows, it gave Excel 3.0 developers the feature set to incorporate into Excel before the technology was widely available to other developers. (Computer Reseller News, 3/18/91). By allowing the applications developers to have an advantage over third-party developers, Microsoft held a significant advantage that it parlayed into applications **dominance**.

http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/cs201/projects/corporate-monopolies/development_microsoft.html

The Business Dictionary includes an entry for **dominant firm**.

> Firm that controls at least half of the market in which it operates and has no significant competition. Its competitors are mostly small firms who compete with each other for the remaining market share.

http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/dominant-firm.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you use *success* or its synonyms as a noun, then there are many possibilities with positive connotations.

When you don't wish to include the connotation of eternal success, use adjectives that focus on other aspects. Some of them are **reverberating success** and **lasting success**.

See **reverberate**, defined by [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reverberate) as

> Have continuing and serious effects.

However you could exaggerate a bit by using adjectives like *Perpetual*, *ceaseless/incessant*, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Success in the long term:  **sustained preeminence** (Google)

> **sus·tained** səˈstānd/ adjective adjective: sustained [https://www.google.com/search?q=define+sustained&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20sustained&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)
>
> ```
> continuing for an extended period or without interruption.
> "several years of sustained economic growth"
> ```
>
> **pre·em·i·nence** [Google definition https://www.google.com/search?q=define+sustained&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20sustained&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)prēˈemənəns/ noun noun: pre-eminence; plural noun:
>   pre-eminences; noun: preeminence; plural noun: preeminences
>
> ```
> the fact of surpassing all others; superiority.
> "the region has never regained the economic preeminence that it once enjoyed"
> synonyms: superiority, supremacy, greatness, excellence, distinction, prominence, predominance, eminence, importance, prestige,
> ```
>
> stature, fame, renown, celebrity
>       "the preeminence of Flemish and Dutch painters was unchallenged"

Answer (score 0):

how about:

**thrive** or ***thriving***

> ***[thrive](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/thriving?s=t)***
>   [thrahyv]
>
> verb (used without object), thrived or throve, thrived or thriven  [thriv-uh n] (Show IPA), thriving.
>
> 1.
>   to prosper; be fortunate or successful.
>
> 2.
>   to grow or develop vigorously; flourish:
>
> *The children thrived in the country.*